# Doctrine2: order associated entity by property of another entity related to it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let A, B, C be associated entities. I'm aiming for `A->getBs()` to return a collection of `B` ordered by two properties: `B.createdAt` and `B.C.displayOrder`.

First works fine, second does not: I've tried `"c.displayOrder" = "asc"`, but this has been unsuccessful (`Unrecognized field: c.displayOrder`).

Is there any way to order by a property from another related entity?

The other option I could imagine is overriding the function `getBs()`, but I wouldn't know how to create a custom DQL query in there to accommodate for my special need. I've read that using the EntityManager inside an Entity is bad practice.

```
A
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a")
  * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "asc", "c.displayOrder" = "asc"})
  */
-id
-getBs()


B
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="C")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */
-id
-createdAt

C
-id
-description
-displayOrder
```

Using doctrine/orm v2.4.5, symfony-standard-edition 2.3.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to these 5 solutions described at question below:

> [Ordering Doctrine Collection based on associated Entity when it is not possible to use the @orderBy annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828669/ordering-doctrine-collection-based-on-associated-entity-when-it-is-not-possible)

Comment: In my research, I had come across those options. It's good to know there aren't better ways to do it. I chose option 4 - implementing a custom `uasort` inside my `getBs()` function. This should be fairly ok design. I accomplished the two-factor sorting by using an if-else structure inside `uasort`.