# Order a result by it's PersistentCollection

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, dql

I have a function to get all "Tours By Network" for today.

*I have a custom repository like this:*

```
public function toursTodayByNetwork($network){

    $todayStart = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") );
    $todayEnd = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d 23:59:59") );

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Tour p JOIN AppBundle:Schedule s WHERE p.id = s.tour AND p.network = :network AND s.start >= :todayStart AND s.start <= :todayEnd'
        )
        ->setParameter('todayStart',$todayStart)
        ->setParameter('todayEnd',$todayEnd)
        ->setParameter('network',$network)
        ->getResult();

}
```

The `Tour` Entity has an `OneToMany` relation to an `Object` Entity.

I would now like to sort the whole thing by the `filiale` column in `AppBundle:Object`, which as you can see is not in the query, so I cannot simply just `ORDER BY`.

**I tried**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedBy="tour")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"filiale" = "DESC"})
 */
protected $object;
```

But that does not change anything.

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29704366/1092632) looks like something I have to do, but I don't understand where to put the EventListener? I also believe I maybe only need to alter the query?

Comment: The annotation "@ORM\OrderBy({"filiale" = "DESC"})" just means that it will sort your related objects in when you do $tour->getObjects();

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your object table :

```
public function toursTodayByNetwork($network){

    $todayStart = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") );
    $todayEnd = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d 23:59:59") );

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Tour p JOIN p.schedule s JOIN p.object o WHERE p.network = :network AND s.start BETWEEN :todayStart AND :todayEnd ORDER BY o.filiale DESC'
        )
        ->setParameter('todayStart',$todayStart)
        ->setParameter('todayEnd',$todayEnd)
        ->setParameter('network',$network)
        ->getResult();

}
```

For the date condition, BETWEEN is a better practice as >= AND <=.

Comment: I tried that as well and it says `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 71: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'o' `

Comment: The syntaxe 'JOIN p.object o' is the normal method to use JOIN in DQL (without 'WHERE p.object = ...' ). I don't know why your write 'JOIN AppBundle:Schedule s' ? May be is that the problem.

Comment: See here : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: That helped to get it working like this `SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Tour p JOIN p.schedule s JOIN p.object o WHERE p.id = s.tour AND p.network = :network AND s.start BETWEEN :todayStart AND :todayEnd ORDER BY o.filiale DESC`BUT it is still not ordered?!

Comment: Remove 'WHERE p.id = s.tour' doctrine does that for you.

Comment: How do you render the result ?